# Which individul IP's would be included in this range?

Tags: vlan

If, for example, the following is allocated to a VLAN, which individual IPs would become usable?

174.121.25.208/29

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/serverfault-wiki-how-does-subnetting-work/49836#49836

Comment: Homework? Best grab yourself one of the numerous subnet calculators available on the Internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a mask calculator like http://cric.grenoble.cnrs.fr/reseau/calculemasque/ (in french, but terms are same)
There is too some CLI tools (something like ipcalc)

```
$ ipcalc 174.121.25.208/29
Address:   174.121.25.208       10101110.01111001.00011001.11010 000
Netmask:   255.255.255.248 = 29 11111111.11111111.11111111.11111 000
Wildcard:  0.0.0.7              00000000.00000000.00000000.00000 111
=>
Network:   174.121.25.208/29    10101110.01111001.00011001.11010 000
HostMin:   174.121.25.209       10101110.01111001.00011001.11010 001
HostMax:   174.121.25.214       10101110.01111001.00011001.11010 110
Broadcast: 174.121.25.215       10101110.01111001.00011001.11010 111
Hosts/Net: 6                     Class B
```

Comment: Ugh... subnet calculators.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you the answer once, but if you are doing VLANing, you really should learn to do the math yourself.

174.121.25.209 - 174.121.25.214

Answer (score 0):

First Usable IP Address = .....: 74.121.25.209
Last Usable IP Address = ......: 74.121.25.214

Look up CIDR notation in case you want to learn more about expressing addesses like this